# Monitor Linux process by user or name

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep, cpanel

i need to get stats from my Centos 6.7 with Cpanel and send to my external monitor server. What I would like to get is an average cpu load per user or per process name in the last 3 minutes. After many research and test not found any praticable solutions apart bash run top with

```
top -d 180 -b -n 2 > /top.log
```

second iteration looks like...

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
38017 mysql     20   0  760m 265m 6324 S  1.4 14.2 244:27.08 mysqld
39501 nobody    20   0 1047m  93m 7068 S  0.1  5.0   0:06.80 httpd
54877 johnd     20   0 32728 3612 2364 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.09 imap
51530 johnd     20   0  353m 5372 1928 S  0.0  0.3   0:04.17 php-fpm
39500 nobody    20   0 1046m  79m 3656 S  0.0  4.3   0:02.57 httpd
    7 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  27:47.61 events/0
39497 nobody    20   0 1046m  84m 7784 S  0.0  4.5   0:02.77 httpd
etc...
```

then grep (only on the second iteration output) with COMMAND or USER, sum and divide by 100 to get value like cpu-load

```
echo "$PRTGTOP" | grep johnd | awk '{ sum += $9; } END { print sum/100; }'
```

I should probably also try to count the process times etc ?, maybe there is a simpler way to achieve the same result, maybe with third-party software to generate stats?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`top` gets its info from `/proc/*/stat`. Each numerical directory under `/proc` is a process number for a currently running process.

It may be easier for you to collect data directly from those directories. The data format is well defined and can be found in `man proc` under the subsection called "/proc/[pid]/stat".

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [`pidstat`](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/man_pidstat.html) tool (part of the [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/) package):

```
pidstat -C httpd -U johnd -h -u 180 1 | awk '{ sum += $7; } END { print sum/100;}'
```

This will return the percentage CPU usage of all processes matching the `httpd` command string and the `johnd` user over a `180`-second interval.

Answer (score -1):

ok, pidstat is better, thanks!, but if USER pid is run for only few seconds no cpu use is reported. i found best result with:

```
#run pidstat with 10 iterations for 18 times
pidstat -U -u 10 18 > /pidstat.log
```

then

```
#sum all cpu usage and divide by 18   

cat /pidstat.log | grep -v Average | grep johnd | awk '{ sum += $8; } END { print sum/100/18;}' OFMT="%3.3f"
cat /pidstat.log | grep -v Average | grep httpd | awk '{ sum += $8; } END { print sum/100/18;}' OFMT="%3.3f"
```

with this i get best cpu usage stat per USER even if process is run only for few seconds but with high cpu usage